# What if Theia Never Hit the Earth?

Tags: gravity, orbital-mechanics, alternate-earth, ecology, astrophysics

Let's say that for some reason, Theia never hit Earth during the formation of the solar system. However, the two heavenly bodies ended up in a stable orbit around each other. Due to this, the Earth's core is smaller, and Earth has a moon with the radius of Mars that orbits at a safe distance. Earth has 90% of the mass of what if the collision happened, and Theia has a mass of about .127 Earth masses. That means that this Earth has a radius of 6.15 thousand km, and a gravity of 9.49 N/kg, while Theia has a surface gravity of 4.39 N/kg. We will assume that Theia and Earth's centers of mass are 400 thousand km from each other. What effects will there be on tides, rotational velocity, tectonic activity, and the development and evolution of life? And will Theia host life in that scenario?

Comment: *"The two heavenly bodies ended up in a stable orbit around each other":* how could they possibly do it? I would seriously consider dropping the off-putting impossibility and just concentrate on the effects of the Moon being ten times heavier while remaining at the same distance from Earth. (Note that tidal forces will be ten times larger.) (Also note than the part about rotational speed cannot be answered unless you specify the initial conditions.) (Finally, you may want to delete the overly broad part about the *"development and evolution of life"*.)

Comment: If Theia doesn't hit Earth, capture is _extremely unlikely_ to happen  unless something significantly massive already in orbit of Earth, or in orbit of Theia, carries off all the momentum needed to slow Theia down through three-body gravitational interactions. Otherwise, at all points where Theia is near Earth, its Earth-relative velocity is always higher than Earth escape velocity for the distance between them.

Comment: @AlexP - actually, the tidal forces may not be just 10 times larger - tidal forces are proportional to the gradient in gravity between the two bodies, not just their relative gravitational forces.  It also is proportional to the inverse cube of the distance for any two bodies.  See this QA on the Astronomy stackexchange: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/39109/how-high-were-the-tides-back-when-the-moon-was-much-closer-to-earth/39126#39126  
And the relevant Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_force#Formulation

Comment: The question is too broad imo. While it is not totally out of the question imo that Theia, had it formed e.g. in a Lagrange Point and slowly drifted towards earth, could eventually have been captured, anything else about 4.5 billion years of evolution is up to the story teller, imo ... but formation and collision "style" is unclear anyway.

Comment: @IronEagle: There is no such thing as "the gradient in gravity between the two bodies"; you probably mean the gradient of gravitational force across the affected body. Tidal forces are proportional to size of the affected body (here Earth which stays pretty much of the same size) and the mass of the body producing the tidal force (here the ten times larger Moon), and inversely proportional to the cube of the distance between the bodies (which stays almost the same). Ten times larger is a good approximation. (You made me actually do the calculation; the actual value is about 10.9 times larger.)

Comment: Yeah, the gradient creates tides. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_force

Comment: @a_donda: Bodies coming from outer space cannot "slowly drift" towards Earth. A body coming from outer space will hit Earth with a *minimum* speed of 11 km/s (40,000 km/h, 25,000 mph); or it may miss Earth going with about the same speed. It *cannot* enter orbit around Earth unless it has engines to slow it down at the right time.

Comment: @AlexP - Good on you for doing the actual calculation, I was a bit too lazy. I am a bit confused on what you mean by "there is no such thing as the gradient in gravity".  A body (the ocean) between Earth and Theia here would feel differing amounts of attraction towards one body or another depending on where it was, is this not a gradient?  Perhaps I phrased it poorly.

Comment: @AlexP It is unclear where Theia formed. It may have come from the outer solar system, it may have formed in a Lagrange point, several scenarios are in discussion.

Comment: @IronEagle: It is the gradient in gravitational force across Earth, not between Earth and the Moon or the Sun. The tidal force is due to the difference in gravitational force between the point on Earth closest to the Moon and the point farthest away from the Moon. (That's where the inversely proportional to the cube of the distance and proportional to size of the affected body come from.)

Comment: @a_donda: It doesn't matter where it formed. If it comes from outside Earth's sphere of influence, it comes with 11 km/s *or more*. (And it cannot enter orbit around Earth because 11 km/s is too fast, *exactly* because it comes from outside Earth's sphere of influence.)

Comment: @AlexP: I say it is unclear where Theia formed and how the collision took place. It is even unclear if it happened at all. But what is much more unclear is how the whole evolution would change if Theia was hypothetically captured. And Earth captures solar system objects today, and releases them again, this is not totally out of the question, though improbable, ofc. Relative velocities change because of encounters, that's how we get probes out there and back again ;-)

Answer (score -2):

**A lot of Questions**

First, you kind of have to ask how they end up in a Stable orbit. Last time i looked, Theia came in pretty fast. But ok lets say that does happen.

The Inital Orbit would be very hyperbolic. And considering the mass of both Bodys, they still might have collided. But if not, they would become a Binary system.

In the first few Million years, not to much would be different. Theia and the Earth would slowly transition into a Perfectly circular Orbit. They would also be locked to each other. So the same side of Both bodys always face each other. This would have one great effect on Tides. Them not being there.

**No tight Tides**

On Earth, the Moon is locked to us but we not to her. This means, if you where to draw a line for the Moon to earth, it would travel over the Planet. This motion creates the Tides.

But, since Theia and the Earth would be to 100% locked to each other, you can say goodby to any sort of tides. Because remember, they dont move in respect to each other. Theia is always at the same spot in the sky, for ever. Same the other way around. So there is not Force change.

**No normal Day night Cycle**

Lets assume both worlds rotate around there Barycenter once a day. So 360* every 24hr. This would mean once per day, there would be a total solar eclipse for both Planets. Not to mention that the "Night" would be more like dawn since a giant reflector, aka the other Planet, does its very best to make your Night, day.

**The Magnetic Field Problem**

So there is one major problem. The Collision with Theia gave the Earth a lot of Angular Momentum. Which probably created or Strong Magnetic Field. No collision means we can say goodby to that too. Which is beyond bad. As far as we can tell, only Mercury has a Magnetic field besides earth while being a Rocky Planet. And its not like Mercurys field is strong.

**Life**

Yeah... No. The most honest Answer is that life would most likly not appear on any of the two Worlds. Without a Magnetic field, both would loss there Atmosphere in little time and with that, the Oceans would Dunkirk this place.

The lack of a Magnetic field kills it. We can currently only come to the conclusion that Theia gave us a Magnetic field, since no other Planet has one besides Mercury. And so by removing this Collision, life cannot start.

Sorry.

But ok lets say the Magnetic field was created by some other mechanism we dont yet know of. Ok fine. Still Theia has no field. Probably, but ok lets say she has to. What then ?

**No Dunkirk !!!**

If both have fields, they would merge into one which would allow Organic Matter and DNA to go from one Planet to the other without being Firebombed by Radiaton. If life starts on one Planet, the other one will have it too very soon. Thus, you can expect that life on both Plantes will be roughly similar. Beyond that, we cant say fuck all m8. Its Evolution, anything can happen.

Comment: I would be very interested to see how they could have ended up in a binary system. With numbers.

Comment: Me too :D As i said, unlikly but hell -2 ? Thats sad D: 

Ok so the only way i see that working is: Theia is in a roughly Parallel Orbit and gets slowed down by something. But my Major is in CS so i cant say to much about the math. 

But then again, the question is not to concerned about the how but the what then. And stranger things have happened ;D

Comment: Hi, i am another -1er, because the magnetic field doesn't result from angular momentum in the bulk but from convection in the core and because I can't follow that categorical "no life" argument.

Comment: They just keep getting more D:

As i said, we dont know what caused the strong field but we have the idea that Theias collision caused it. This would fit. The Field is generated by the Interaction between the Core and other Layers. The Interaction is a result of Rotation as far as i am concernd. Where this rotation came from, well Theia, Space Jesus. You name it. 

As for life. No Magnetic field = no atmosphere = No oceans = no life.

Comment: @Erik: Venus has an a atmosphere, but no (internal) magnetic field. Some gas giants' moons are hypothesized to have oceans ...

Comment: Look at Venus. Her Atmosphere is what 90bar ? And full of Acid. Sure, Europa, Ganymed and so on probably have oceans.... Because of the Tidal forces of Jupiter which would not be there thus what is the point ?

Comment: Don't take it personal :-) But anthropocentrism and monocausality may blurr the view. We can't categorically exclude life on other solar system bodies. Venus' atmopshere was just in discussion (again, yawn). Ok, it was a false alarm ...

Comment: Answer only well asked questions. And this question was too broad from miles away!

Comment: @Erik Hall Do professional scientists speculating about astrobiology believe that the ability of a planet to retain atmosphere depends on its escape velocity, his magnetic field, or a combination of both?  I expect that a planet with 90 percent of Earth's mass would have sufficient escape velocity to retain a dense atmosphere for billions of years.

Comment: Am i a Professional Scientist ? No. Do i just say what i would assume is the most likly outcome ? Yes.